# Sending E-Mail with multiple attachments: "SecurityException when openFileDescriptor" (GMail)

Tags: android, permissions, email-attachments

To send multiple attachments I use this code to create the mail intent:

```
 private Intent buildIntent(FotoBatch fotos) {
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

    email.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);


    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{MAIL_RECIPIENT});

    ...

    // Attachments
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Foto foto : fotos.getFotos()) {
        uris.add(foto.getUri());
    }
    email.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

    return email;
}
```

When there is more than one attachment, the following error message appears

with GMail:

```
2018-10-16 12:07:19.703 4456-4456/? E/Gmail: Gmail:Error adding attachment
    exk: SecurityException when openFileDescriptor.
        at exl.a(SourceFile:8)
...
```

With K9 Mail:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{a320841 7869:com.fsck.k9/u0a195} (pid=7869, uid=10195) that is not exported from UID 10196
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1943)
```

The manifest contains the provider entry

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.timeshuttle.lagerapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

The content of file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.timeshuttle.lagerapp/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

What is missing in the content provider configuration?

Tested Android API Level 27 on an Android 8.0 device.

There is no error if the attachemnt list contains only one item. The mail application opens and shows the attachment (image) correctly.